# Cómo utilizar palabras reservadas en ExtJS (Sencha v4)

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch

Tengo un JS con la palabra `export` (que es reservada para yui compressor) en el `extend` de un controller, asi:

```
extend : 'ejemplo.export.ejemplo'
```

No puedo cambiar la palabra `export` porque es la especificacion del nombre de otro JS que es transversal en otros proyectos, ¿alguien sabe cómo puedo usar esta palabra para que el 'yui' no genere error?

El error es el siguiente:

> [INF] Compressing data with YuiJavascriptCompressor
>
> [ERR] C2009: YUI Parse Error (missing name after . operator =>            extend :  ejemplo.export.ejemplo ,) -- unknown-file:62534:63

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tuve el mismo problema con la palabra export y no encontré una solución rápida, me tocó reemplazarla. Creo que una solución podría ser editar el código de yui compressor para remover restricciones al menos para esa palabra, volver a compilar y utilizar. Aquí está el proyecto en github https://github.com/yui/yuicompressor

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, por el momento no es posible realizar una refactorizacion, revisare el código fuente para editar el código, si tienes una guía para documentarme te agradecería.